# Get authentication token from AWS EKS using the AWS Java SDK v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-sdk, amazon-eks, aws-java-sdk-2.x

How can I get a Kubernetes authentication token from AWS EKS using the AWS Java SDK v2?  An authentication token that can then be used to authenticate with Kubernetes using a Kubernetes SDK.  In other words I want to get an authentication token from EKS to use for authentication with Kubernetes so that I don't have to create a "kube config".

I actually got a solution working with AWS Java SDK v1 (not v2) looking at the code examples in the following [open issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1795).  There is also a Python code example [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator#api-authorization-from-outside-a-cluster) BUT I'm not having any success with AWS Java SDK v2.  My attempt at doing it with AWS Java SDK v2:

```java
public static String getAuthenticationToken(AwsCredentialsProvider awsAuth, Region awsRegion, String clusterName) {
    try {
        SdkHttpFullRequest requestToSign = SdkHttpFullRequest
                .builder()
                .method(SdkHttpMethod.GET)
                .uri(new URI("https", String.format("sts.%s.amazonaws.com", awsRegion.id()), null, null))
                .appendHeader("x-k8s-aws-id", clusterName)
                .appendRawQueryParameter("Action", "GetCallerIdentity")
                .appendRawQueryParameter("Version", "2011-06-15")
                .build();

        ZonedDateTime expirationDate = DateUtil.addSeconds(DateUtil.now(), 60);
        Aws4PresignerParams presignerParams = Aws4PresignerParams.builder()
                .awsCredentials(awsAuth.resolveCredentials())
                .expirationTime(expirationDate.toInstant())
                .signingName("sts")
                .signingRegion(awsRegion)
                .build();

        SdkHttpFullRequest signedRequest = Aws4Signer.create().presign(requestToSign, presignerParams);

        String encodedUrl = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(signedRequest.getUri().toString().getBytes(CharSet.UTF_8.getCharset()));
        return ("k8s-aws-v1." + encodedUrl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String errorMessage = "A problem occurred generating an Eks token";
        logger.error(errorMessage, e);
        throw new RuntimeException(errorMessage, e);
    }
}
```

It generates a token, but when I use the token in my Kubernetes client (the official Java Kubernetes SDK) I get back an "Unauthorized" response - so I'm missing something I can't put my finger on...

The AWS Java SDK v1 version looks something like this:
(From the [open issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1795) mentioned earlier)

I got it working, but I'm struggling to get something similar to work in AWS Java SDK v2.

```java
private String generateToken(String clusterName,
                                 Date expirationDate,
                                 String serviceName,
                                 String region,
                                 AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient awsSecurityTokenServiceClient,
                                 AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider,
                                 String scheme,
                                 String host) throws URISyntaxException {
        try {
            DefaultRequest<GetCallerIdentityRequest> callerIdentityRequestDefaultRequest = new DefaultRequest<>(new GetCallerIdentityRequest(), serviceName);
            URI uri = new URI(scheme, host, null, null);
            callerIdentityRequestDefaultRequest.setResourcePath("/");
            callerIdentityRequestDefaultRequest.setEndpoint(uri);
            callerIdentityRequestDefaultRequest.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);
            callerIdentityRequestDefaultRequest.addParameter("Action", "GetCallerIdentity");
            callerIdentityRequestDefaultRequest.addParameter("Version", "2011-06-15");
            callerIdentityRequestDefaultRequest.addHeader("x-k8s-aws-id", clusterName);

            Signer signer = SignerFactory.createSigner(SignerFactory.VERSION_FOUR_SIGNER, new SignerParams(serviceName, region));
            SignerProvider signerProvider = new DefaultSignerProvider(awsSecurityTokenServiceClient, signer);
            PresignerParams presignerParams = new PresignerParams(uri,
                    credentialsProvider,
                    signerProvider,
                    SdkClock.STANDARD);

            PresignerFacade presignerFacade = new PresignerFacade(presignerParams);
            URL url = presignerFacade.presign(callerIdentityRequestDefaultRequest, expirationDate);
            String encodedUrl = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(url.toString().getBytes());
            log.info("Token [{}]", encodedUrl);
            return "k8s-aws-v1." + encodedUrl;
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            log.error("could not generate token", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As indicated in the AWS Java SDK v1 issue, the implementation is sensitive to specifying a too long expiration date.  I did play around with the expiration date a bit, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: did you tried using the aws-iam-authenticator utility to get tokens

Comment: I've used the aws-iam-authenticator before, but I need to be able to generate tokens from Java source code - without installing anything.  And I have gotten this stuff to work with AWS Java SDK v1, just having problems with v2 of the SDK.

Comment: I am currently using the AWS Java SDK v1 to generate the token - but now I have to have it on my classpath :(  As soon as I can figure this out I can refactor and remove v1 of the SDK from my dependencies :)

Comment: What Kubernetes version are you running? Where is this app meant to run (outside of cluster, inside of it)?

Comment: I'm using the latest version available on EKS, so that is Kubernetes version 1.14.  The application needs to run outside of the cluster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I finally got it working.

The AWS Java SDK v2 version:

```java
public static String getAuthenticationToken(AwsCredentialsProvider awsAuth, Region awsRegion, String clusterName) {
    try {    
        SdkHttpFullRequest requestToSign = SdkHttpFullRequest
                .builder()
                .method(SdkHttpMethod.GET)
                .uri(StsUtil.getStsRegionalEndpointUri(awsRegion))
                .appendHeader("x-k8s-aws-id", clusterName)
                .appendRawQueryParameter("Action", "GetCallerIdentity")
                .appendRawQueryParameter("Version", "2011-06-15")
                .build();

        ZonedDateTime expirationDate = DateUtil.addSeconds(DateUtil.now(), 60);
        Aws4PresignerParams presignerParams = Aws4PresignerParams.builder()
                .awsCredentials(awsAuth.resolveCredentials())
                .signingRegion(awsRegion)
                .signingName("sts")
                .signingClockOverride(Clock.systemUTC())
                .expirationTime(expirationDate.toInstant())
                .build();

        SdkHttpFullRequest signedRequest = Aws4Signer.create().presign(requestToSign, presignerParams);

        String encodedUrl = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(signedRequest.getUri().toString().getBytes(CharSet.UTF_8.getCharset()));
        return ("k8s-aws-v1." + encodedUrl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String errorMessage = "A problem occurred generating an Eks authentication token for cluster: " + clusterName;
        logger.error(errorMessage, e);
        throw new RuntimeException(errorMessage, e);
    }
}
```

The problem was in my STS endpoint Uri:

```java
public static URI getStsRegionalEndpointUri(Region awsRegion) {
    try {
        return new URI("https", String.format("sts.%s.amazonaws.com", awsRegion.id()), "/", null);
    } catch (URISyntaxException shouldNotHappen) {
        String errorMessage = "An error occurred creating the STS regional endpoint Uri";
        logger.error(errorMessage, shouldNotHappen);
        throw new RuntimeException(errorMessage, shouldNotHappen);
    }
}
```

Note the `/` in the `path` (third) argument for the `URI` object.  The AWS Java SDK v1 version didn't create the URI like that, but specified the `/` elsewhere.  If I now print out the `URI` as a String I get `https://sts.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/`, while the original version in the question just returned `https://sts.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

Interesting enough - the original version did also generate a token, but the token was rejected by Kubernetes.  One should expect similar behavior if the expiration date is too far into the future - you'll get a token, but it will lead to an `Unauthorized` response from the Kubernetes service.

After changing the STS endpoint everything worked, but I made one more change:

I added the following line to my `Aws4PresignerParams`:

```java
.signingClockOverride(Clock.systemUTC())
```

It wasn't required, but the original AWS Java SDK v1 did do something with a clock when it specified `SdkClock.STANDARD`, and the `ZonedDateTime` that I use in the AWS Java SDK v2 version does use the UTC timezone.

Comment: So yes, I got it working, but I don't have too much insight into the reasoning behind it.  Even without the `/` I still got a token, but as indicated it just didn't work when I started to integrate with Kubernetes.

Comment: Just another interesting aside - the original AWS Java SDK v1 issue did indicate that the token is very short-lived.  As soon as I try to set the expiration date to more than 60 seconds the same thing happens - I get a token, but it leads to an `Unauthorized` response.

Comment: Hi – how did you use the token to init the EKS client to connect to cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness sake, in case you want to use the token with the Kubernetes client ([io.kubernetes:client-java](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.kubernetes/client-java-api/latest/index.html)), you can add an interceptor that generates a valid token before every request:

```
  private ApiClient createClient(AwsCredentialsProvider awsAuth, Region awsRegion, String clusterName) {

    ApiClient client = Config.fromUrl(eksEndpoint, false);
    OkHttpClient httpClient = createHttpClient(client.getHttpClient(), awsAuth, awsRegion, clusterName);
    client.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    return client;
  }

  @NotNull
  private OkHttpClient createHttpClient(
      OkHttpClient baseHttpClient, AwsCredentialsProvider awsAuth, Region awsRegion, String clusterName
  ) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder(baseHttpClient);
    builder.addInterceptor(chain -> {
      Request request = chain.request();
      String token = getAuthenticationToken(awsAuth, awsRegion, clusterName);
      Request newRequest = request
          .newBuilder()
          .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
          .build();
      return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    });
    return builder.build();
  }
```